# Conditional formatting rule that compares against a range of values

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I have a list of 2019 dates (col A) and holiday dates (col G). Wherever there's a date in col A that matches any date in the range G2:G20, I would like to highlight it in grey. See this [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Iyprfjy4NmbKy-_9_aEN2OD04yDzc5EH5slWRQUsqn0/edit?usp=sharing)

So far I have this custom formula 
`=$A:$A=$G$2:$G$20`

...which only marks the first instance of the date range. Is there any way I can solve this without having to create a separate rule for each element of col G?

Comment: In Excel, using non-array formulas provides some advantages over array formulas, whenever the same result can be obtained.
I am not sure the same applies for Goggle Sheets, but given that possibility the solution posted might be preferred over one with `ARRAYFORMULA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **custom formula:**

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, G$2:G, 1, 0))), 1))
  ```

  [image]
- for row highlight (A:E) try:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2:A,$G$2:G,1,0))),1))
  ```

  [image]

Comment: Any way to highlight the whole row (from col A to col E) for the greyed out dates?

Comment: @jlo answer updated

Answer (score 2):

If you have your data in, say, `A2:A200` (assuming a header row), and you holidays are stored in `G2:G20`, then set a Conditional Formatting rule with:

*Apply to range*: `A2:A200`

*Custom formula is*: `=SUMPRODUCT((A2=($G$2:$G$20)))>=1`

You could also use
*Apply to range*: `A2:E`
to also color columns `B:E` and to not limit the number of rows.

In Excel, [using non-array formulas provides some advantages over array formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20086410/2707864), whenever the same result can be obtained.
I am not sure the same applies for Goggle Sheets, but given that possibility **the present solution might be preferred over one with `ARRAYFORMULA`**.